# Pass onBlur and sx props in slotsProp of MUI DatePicker 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this DatePicker component using MUI DatePicker v6.

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
// @ts-nocheck
import * as React from 'react';
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import './common.css';
import { DatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
export const CustomDatePicker = (props) => {
  const { control, name, label } = props;
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({ field: { onChange, value, ref }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
          <DatePicker
            size="small"
            name={name}
            label={label}
            control={control}
            format="DD-MMM-YYYY"
            value={value}
            onChange={(event) => {
              onChange(event);
            }}
            disableFuture
            sx={{ width: props.width ?? 250 }}
            InputProps={{
              style: {
                padding: 8
              }
            }}
            disableMaskedInput
            slotProps={{
              textField: {
                helperText: error?.message,
                error: error?.message ? true : false,
                size: 'small',
                readOnly: true
                //add sx here
                //add onBlur here
              }
            }}
          />
        </LocalizationProvider>
      )}
    />
  );
};
export default CustomDatePicker;
```

I want to set an `onBlur` and `sx` props on generated `TextField` component but don't know the correct format when props are set as JSON object. Cannot find any example in the documentation too.

Answer (score 1):

the correct format for setting the onBlur and sx props on the generated TextField component

```
<DatePicker 
   format="DD-MMM-YYYY"
   onChange={(event) => {
     console.log('Input blurred. Value:');
   }}
   disableFuture
   sx={{ width:  250 }}
   slotProps={{
     textField: {

       sx: {
         backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
         borderRadius: 4,
         '& input': {
           backgroundColor: 'green',
         },
       },
       onBlur: (event) => {
         console.log('Input blurred. Value:', event.target.value);
       }
     }
   }}
  />
```

[you can view here in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-feather-j8l8wr?file=/Demo.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same question, and I ended up finding [an issue](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/8962#issuecomment-1545233773) on the MUI Github where one of the members of the MUI team [provided a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-keldysh-b0ge1f?file=/demo.tsx:728-1093) (and mentioned that this is not documented...):

```
<StyledDateRangePicker
  localeText={{ start: "Check-in", end: "Check-out" }}
  slotProps={{
    desktopPaper: {
      sx: {
        backgroundColor: "white"
      }
    },
    layout: {
      sx: {
        backgroundColor: "white"
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

However, if you're trying to access the `TextField` input element, you may not be able to get at it through the `sx` prop as demonstrated above. I ended up needing to drill down into it like so:

```
<DatePicker
  sx={{ width: '100%' }}
  slotProps={{ textField: { InputProps: { style: { borderRadius: 0 } } } }}
  ...
/>
```

The [Advanced Configuration section](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/#advanced-configuration) of the TextField docs were useful here, though I got tripped up on `inputProps` vs `InputProps` - the capitalized version is key here (it applies the props to the MUI Input component, rather than applying attributes to the HTML input element, as far as I can tell from [the docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/#TextField-prop-InputProps)).